# Retain order of elements using different selectors with puppeteer on a page with a flat structure

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a page with a flat structure where the order the elements appear on the page defines the structure I need to maintain when saving the data.

```html
<div class='parent'>
<h3 class="'group">Furniture</h3>
<h4 class="category">Office</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Desk</li>
  <li>Chairs</li>
</ul>
<h4 class="category">Home</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Couches</li>
  <li>Tables</li>
  <li>Bookshelves</li>
</ul>
<h4 class="category">Outdoor</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Shade Umbrellas</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3 class="'group">Toys</h3>
<h4 class="category">Toddlers</h4>
<h4 class="category">Kids</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Balls</li>
  <li>Dolls</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

There are enough good query selectors for me to pull everything I need from the page, but I can't figure out how to tell puppeteer to organize categories by groups and li elements by categories.

-- added on edit --

Since posting this, I have put all of the HTML from the parent div into a variable using:

```js
let allHTML = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.parent')).map(el => el.innerHTML);
  })
```

I am now working on slicing up the allHTML variable to get blocks of text binned by group and category. Then, I can use these blocks to recreate the organizational structure on the page.

This should work, but it is cumbersome. I'm hoping there is a more straightforward way to have puppeteer retain the order of elements selected with different query selectors allowing me to determine which instances of .category (or `<h4>`) come after each instance of .group (or `<h3>`)element.

Comment: So can we assume you have the HTML as stated in a variable? What is the expected resulting object? What have you tried?

Comment: I can get the HTML in a variable with .innerHTML, and I have the names of the classes I want. At the time of posting this, all I had done was to get all of the target elements in separate arrays (groups, categories, and li elements), but the nesting structure was gone. The arrays do not include information about which category goes with which group. I will update the post with some information about what I've done since posting.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: A nested object that retains the organizational structure from the page  - like the json object in Peter Thoeny's solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not well defined, so I make some assumptions:

- build a nested object from group ==> category => list items
- use `group` class to determine the group
- use `category` class to determine the category
- a category belongs to the previous group sibling
- a list belongs to the previous category sibling

**Solution:**

```js
const html = `<h3 class="group">Furniture</h3> <h4 class="category">Office</h4> <ul> <li>Desk</li> <li>Chairs</li> </ul>
<h4 class="category">Home</h4> <ul> <li>Couches</li> <li>Tables</li> <li>Bookshelves</li> </ul> <h4 class="category">Outdoor</h4> <ul> <li>Shade Umbrellas</li> </ul> </div> <h3 class="'group">Toys</h3> <h4 class="category">Toddlers</h4> <h4 class="category">Kids</h4> <ul> <li>Balls</li> <li>Dolls</li> </ul>`;

const el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = html;
let result = {};
let groupVal = '';
let categoryVal = '';
Array.from(el.children).forEach(e => {
  if(e.classList.contains('group')) {
    groupVal = e.innerText;
    result[groupVal] = {};
  } else if(e.classList.contains('category')) {
    categoryVal = e.innerText;
    result[groupVal][categoryVal] = {};
  } else if(e.tagName === 'UL') {
    result[groupVal][categoryVal] = Array.from(e.children).map(li => li.innerText);
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, ' '));
```

**Output:**

```
{
 "Furniture": {
  "Office": [
   "Desk",
   "Chairs"
  ],
  "Home": [
   "Couches",
   "Tables",
   "Bookshelves"
  ],
  "Outdoor": [
   "Shade Umbrellas"
  ],
  "Toddlers": {},
  "Kids": [
   "Balls",
   "Dolls"
  ]
 }
}
```

**Note:** Instead of using `.createElement()` on html text you could get the inner HTML from the DOM (here done just to demo the solution)

Comment: This is perfect. I thought Puppeteer might be able to parse the order from the page, but bringing the text in and then using straight JS to process it makes sense. Your solution is much cleaner than what I was working towards.